# Example studies that use inferences from cross-validation of the entire dataset

Tags: cross-validation, dataset, research-design, elicitation

I am performing a study where I perform inferences based on cross-validation metrics that use the entire dataset. My reasoning behind this is (a) my dataset is small and imbalanced and (b) this is purely for inferential research purposes, not a production model. I am also stratifying my folds, so that each fold has an equal proportion of both the majority and minority classes.

I was told that this practice is common in fields like biomedical research, where data is scarce.

**EDIT**: To clarify, I'm just looking for example studies to cite in my thesis, to show that the methodology has been used before.

Comment: Could you share what you are trying to infer? If you're trying to infer the value of a parameter (like a beta coefficient), cross validation is the wrong thing to do. If you're  trying to infer which model performs better, cross validation may be helpful

Comment: I'm just looking for examples of other studies/papers that have done this, so I can mention in my thesis that it's been done before.

Comment: Cross-validation is a type of resampling procedure, so you draw samples without replacement from your dataset, but cross-validation is a method for assessing the uncertainty of a model, not the dataset itself. Whoever told you that "this practice is common in...biomedical research where data is scarce." is perhaps mistaken. In fact, the only reference that comes to mind is Frank Harrell's regression modeling strategies where he advises to bootstrap rather than perform CV to assess predictiveness. (this is based on my own foggy memory, but at least you have a reference to check)

Comment: I'm particularly confused what you mean to "cross-validate an *entire* dataset" as if there was a way to cross-validate "part" of a dataset. Stratification still applies to the whole dataset, but I expect that any observation with a 100% probability of inclusion in resampling will not provide reliable estimates of uncertainty. Others may confirm whether this is true.